# Boost: How to build and install multiple toolsets

Tags: c++, boost

I need to build and install boost libraries for multiple toolsets, including clang. Is there a guide on how to do this?

Since most of boost is header only, that part should be shared by all installs.

Also the list of toolsets in the docs do not include clang, which is really strange since it is a popular compiler. In fact it is the standard compiler on OSX platforms and often used on Linux.

Comment: It seem to actually have clang, and perhaps other instructions you are looking for right here: https://boostorg.github.io/build/manual/develop/index.html#bbv2.overview.configuration

Comment: Skeptical, thanks, could you elevate that to an answer and I'll accept it. Hard to find the right info in a complex system. FYI: I' considering bundling boost with my product, which supports multiple simultaneous targets, so I'm trying to evaluate what I can do with a bundled version automatically using my own configuration setup. A typical problem is that libc++ and libstdc++ aren't compatible so code built for one isn't compatible with the other.

Comment: BTW: the above docs tell me how to use boost build (b2), but don't quite answer how to use make it so the boost libraries themselves can be built with multiple toolchains (without modifying anything in the boost repo). Presumably I can get the build script boost uses and modify it, but this creates a maintenance issue. Rather I'd like to build the standard way but add "overrides" externally so upgrades require less maintenance.